# Asp.net listview control

Tags: asp.net

Here i am using listbox to populate the data from database. In this listbox i have one button and the name of button is delete. Here i am using also ajax. So if you click on the delete button it is showing the confirmation message " Are you sure to delete this item". To show the confirmation message i am using the ajax control and its name is "ConfirmButtonExtender". and its attribute is ConfirmText="Are you sure want to Delete?". So my question is how to show the message with name of the product like "Are you sure want to Delete keyboard?" So here instead of keyborad it will be change, depend on selected item. so how can i do it, Please help me. Here is my code :

```
<td runat="server" id="action">          
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" AlternateText="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" ImageUrl="../images/icons/fugue/pencil.png" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" AlternateText="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" ImageUrl="../images/icons/fugue/cross-circle.png"/>
</td>
<cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID ="ibtnDelete" ConfirmText="Are you sure want to Delete?" OnClientCancel ="CancelClick">
</cc1:ConfirmButtonExtender>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ConfirmText='Are you sure want to Delete <%# DataBinder.Eval("ProductNameFieldGoesHere") %> ?'
```

Comment: I do it like that but it is saying parser error. ok any way i am going to again try. Thank for help. wait i am here ...

Comment: Hello tried your code. it is running but data is not fetching from database. I am getting this error please help me. This type of message is showing when i click on delete button.                  Are you sure want to Delete <%# DataBinder.Eval("login_name") %> ?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay... been in and out of meetings. The types of quotes used is significant. Was that the issue?